# Buttons not being placed inside the correct frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend, customtkinter

I am a newbie trying to use tkinter to build a GUI for an application. So far, I have a frame that I'd like to put several buttons into. However, every time I attempt to position this button, it isn't placed properly, being put outside of the frame itself. I wouldn't like to use the place function because of the several buttons I have to dynamically generate coming from an excel sheet so I was hoping to use the grid function instead.

Here is what I have so far

```
from tkinter import *
from customtkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.state("zoomed")
window.title("My Company's Description Printer")

main_frame = CTkFrame(window, width=1920, height=1080, fg_color="grey21")
main_frame.place(x=0, y=0)

title = Label(main_frame,
              text="My Company",
              bg="grey21",
              fg="white",
              font=("Trajan Pro", 20)).place(x=626, y=30)

button_frame = CTkCanvas(main_frame,
                         width=800,
                         height=600,
                         highlightthickness=3,
                         highlightbackground="black",
                         relief="ridge",
                         bg="grey19").place(x=60, y=110)

test_button = CTkButton(button_frame, text="test").grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

[Example of code being ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCXx.png)

As you can see, the button is being placed in the top left corner of the entire window rather than the top left corner of the black bordered button frame. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try not using `place`

Comment: Note that `button_frame` is `None`, so `test_button` is child of root window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `button_frame` is `None` because it is the result of `.place(...)`, so  the button (`test_button` is `None` as well due to same reason) is a child of the root window instead of the instance of `CTkCanvas`. `.place(...)` should be called in separate line.

Also `.create_window()` is used instead of tkinter layout manager to put widget into a canvas:

```py
...
button_frame = CTkCanvas(main_frame,
                         width=800,
                         height=600,
                         highlightthickness=3,
                         highlightbackground="black",
                         relief="ridge",
                         bg="grey19")
# call .place(...) in separate line
button_frame.place(x=60, y=110)

test_button = CTkButton(button_frame, text="test") # don't use .grid(row=0, column=0)
# use .create_window() to put widget into canvas
button_frame.create_window(0, 0, window=test_button, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a difference in using .place() like that. If I wanted to put multiple buttons in the frame wouldn't it be a better idea to use .grid()?

Comment: Then better use `CTkFrame` instead of `CTkCanvas`.